# How to update the link table of a Many to Many relationship based on a recursive property of one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, sql-delete

In my application I'm using role based access control to Authenticate and Authorize users. Each user can be assigned multiple roles and these roles provide access to permissions.

Each role is part of a hierarchy, with the Verified role being at the top of the tree. All other roles inherit from it using a self-referential relationship in the table. The default roles table looks like this, with a Moderator and Developer role that inherit from Verified, and an Admin role that inherits from Moderator.

```
roles table
id name       parent role
1  verified   none
2  moderator  verified
3  developer  verified
4  admin      moderator
```

When assigning roles to users, I want to enforce that parents are required, meaning that if a User has the Admin role they must also have Moderator and Verified. This means that if the user loses their Moderator role, their Admin role should automatically be deleted, and if the parent of the Admin role is changed to Developer, then the user should lose the Admin role as they no longer have the required parent.

So far the only solution I have thought of includes adding a new column on the link table that references the parent ranks that have already been assigned, for example:

```
role-user link table
id  role       user_id  parent role-user link
1   verified   1        none
2   moderator  1        1
3   admin      1        2
```

This would mean if I removed the Moderator role from User 1 they would lose the Admin role, but if I changed the parent of the Admin role to Developer, the Moderator and Admin roles would not be deleted from the link table. Is there a way I can achieve this functionality with just SQL / Foreign Key constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table with a structure like so:

```
create table role_user (
    user_id int,
    role_id int,
    parent_role_id int,
    primary key (user_id, role_id)
);
```

The hierarchy relationships is described in the table itself. To enforce integrity, you can have a self-referencing compound foreign key on `(user_id, parent_role_id)` that references another row in the same table, on columns `(user_id, role_id)`. With this set up at hand, you just need to enable option `on delete cascade` to get the behavior that youw want:

```
create table role_user (
    user_id int,
    role_id int,
    parent_role_id int,
    primary key (user_id, role_id),
    foreign key (user_id, parent_role_id) 
        references role_user(user_id, role_id) 
        on delete cascade
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7024387ca9edb02cb4c9ad1c5495cae)**:

```
-- sample data
select * from role_user;

user_id | role_id | parent_role_id
------: | ------: | -------------:
      1 |       1 |           
      1 |       2 |              1
      1 |       3 |              2


-- delete the top node in the hierarchy
delete from role_user where user_id = 1 and role_id = 1;

-- all children rows are deleted as well
select * from role_user;

user_id | role_id | parent_role_id
------: | ------: | -------------:
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this by storing the parent_role_id within the roles table, because if it is in the role_user table there wouldn't be an easy way to update the roles heirarchy

Comment: @user2166538: well, possibly, but that's a different question than the one you originally asked really. I used the data structure that you provided in your question, where both the role id and parent id are in the user_role table.